# Discord.js For each user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried making an Interval and searching for a Guild and so on but it always says that it cannot Read the property 'users' of undefined and I don't seem to find the Problem here is the code I tried

```js
setInterval(function () {
  client.guilds.find(g => g.id == '419967722349133825').users.forEach(function (guildMember) {
      if (fs.existsSync("Warns for " + guildMember.id)) fs.unlinkSync("Warns for " + guildMember.id)
  }) 
}, 2629800000);
```

Error Message

```
(node:11504) TimeoutOverflowWarning: 2629800000 does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer.
Timeout duration was set to 1.

client.guilds.find(g => g.id == '419967722349133825').users.forEach(function (guildMember) {
                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure that `419967722349133825` is a valid guild ID? The error means that the `client.guilds.find()` hasn't returned anything. This could be because the ID is not a valid guild ID or perhaps your bot isn't in the guild with that ID

Comment: the guild Id I used is valid and the bot is also in the guild

Answer (score 0):

The `users` field is undefined because there was no guilds with that matching id. Double check that the id is the id of the guild you're after and that your bot is a member of that guild.

When getting a signle guild by id from a `Collection`, you can use the `get()` method. The `get()` method is a method on the vanilla `Map` object, since Discord.js' `Collection` extends `Map`, and the key for each guild in that Collection, is the guild id.

Comment: The id of the guild I want to find is correct but I still get the same error also I tried the get method but the get method doesn't work either and the bot is in the server

Comment: @Link try logging the output of `Array.from(client.guilds.keys())` and see if your guild id is in there.